# After running npm run android command, process stucked at 62%

Tags: android, react-native, command-line-interface

Hello guys I am facing an issues on my windows 11 laptop while running npm `run android` command after `react-native start`, whenever I run `npm run android` it starts the process but the process stucked on 62%, it is not showing any error.
Is there something worng with command or with my pc

[image]

I have tried these commands too to run on android

```
npx react-native run-android, 
npm react-native run-android, 
react-native run-android
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "demoapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.10.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.70.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Open your project in android studio and Clean Project and run it. You need to upgrade your Gradle.

or

you can fire a command

1. cd android
2. ./gradlew clean
3. cd ..
4. npx react-native run-android

// if you are using yarn package then fire

yarn android

I hope it works for you.

Comment: this comand didn't work "./gradlew clean" but "gradlew clear build" worked